# p5 object renders weirdly after shifting an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

In [this](https://codepen.io/garritfra/pen/PQomgK?editors=0110) pen, I'm having the problem that the last ball in the array does not show for a split second. I believe that's because upon shifting the array, the objects have to rerender, but I can't seem to find a solution for this fix.

```
function draw() {
  background(0);
  noStroke();

  console.log(balls);
  balls.forEach((i) => {
    i.show();
    i.radius += 1;
    i.opacity -= 1;
    if (i.opacity == 150) {
      let newBall = new Ball(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, size, opacity);
      balls.push(newBall);
    }
    if (i.opacity == 0) {
      balls.shift();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't add or remove object from an array as you iterate over it using the `forEach()` function.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> The range of elements processed by `forEach()` is set before the first invocation of `callback`. Elements that are appended to the array after the call to `forEach()` begins will not be visited by `callback`. If the values of existing elements of the array are changed, the value passed to `callback` will be the value at the time `forEach()` visits them; elements that are deleted before being visited are not visited. If elements that are already visited are removed (e.g. using `shift()`) during the iteration, later elements will be skipped

In other words, think harder about what this `if` statement is doing:

```
if (i.opacity == 0) {
  balls.shift();
}
```

Here, you check whether `i` (the **current** ball) has an opacity of zero, and if so, you then remove the **first** ball. This is almost certainly not what you want to do.

Googling "javascript modify array during forEach" will return a ton of results. Hint: you might consider splitting this up into two steps: one that loops over the array and adds new balls, and another step that loops over the array and removes the balls you want to delete. Basic `for` loops will get you pretty far here.